# How to mask action faster in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using below function for millions of time in read/write sqlitedb . And it is now a major bottleneck . How I can make it faster for similar result ? I compiled it to module so but still slower part .

BEST

```
def mask_np(byt):
    # Use same function in both directions.  Input and output are bytes
    # objects.
    mask = b'maskstringtoserve'
    lmask = len(mask)
    return bytes(c ^ mask[i % lmask] for i, c in enumerate(byt))
```

Comment: If this is your true application bottleneck, I recommend using Cython to compile down this function to C: https://cython.org/

Comment: Is this a value you should just be storing instead of having to fetch every time? that would at least solve the output

Comment: This function seems very light weight. Are you sure this is the bottleneck? Maybe the fact that you are doing it millions of times is the bottleneck. If you are loading lots of data and then perming this operation, using a dataloader may improve your performance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use numpy:

```
def mask_numpy(val: bytes) -> bytes:
    arr = np.frombuffer(val, dtype=np.int8)
    length = len(value)
    np_mask = np.tile(np.frombuffer(mask, dtype=np.int8),       round(length/mask_length+0.5))[:length]
    masked = arr ^ np_mask
    return masked.tobytes()
```